# Getting deffered saved images in octobercms

Tags: octobercms

Hi there i m using 'uploader' and sitesearch plugin in octobercms.
using uploader plugin i m saving multiple images in my posting model after saving they are showing in the backend area but are not retrieving.
i m retrieving **attachMany relationship postingimage** in this way but when i print {{result.model}} in **content.htm** file it shows null array like this

```
{"title":"gdsag","brandname":"Yamaha","description":"gdsga","price":5887,"name":"Rawalpindi","postingimage":[]}
```

cannot able to get the **deffered saved** images in model
getting images like this in sitesearch plugin

```
if ($item->postingimage) {
                    return [
                        'title' => $item->title,
                        'text' => $item->description,
                        'text' => $item->price,
                        'text' => $item->brandname,
                        'text' => $item->name,
                        'thumb' => $item->postingimage->first(),

                        'relevance' => $relevance, // higher relevance results in a higher
                        'model' => $item, 
                    ];
```

my init method in component

```
public function init()
    {
        $component = $this->addComponent(
            'Responsiv\Uploader\Components\FileUploader',
            'fileUploader',
            ['deferredBinding' => true]
        );


        $component->bindModel('postingimage', new Posting);


    }
```

i m saving the images in this way after form submisssion

```
 $posting->save(null, post('_session_key'));
```

any help?

Comment: can you share your model relation details and html content where you include your component.

Comment: Following is the the model named **Posting** with the relationship
  public $attachMany=[
        'postingimage'=>['System\Models\File', 'order' => 'sort_order']
    ];
and this is the content.htm page

{{result.model}}
{{result.model.price}}
{{result.model.brandname}}
{{result.model.description|raw}}

Comment: i have also posted this problem in site search plugin on github
https://github.com/OFFLINE-GmbH/oc-site-search-plugin/issues/56

Comment: You can see **uploader** plugin and **sitesearch** plugin for more details.

Comment: I m just uploading the muliple images with defferred binding and they can be seen in backend editing screen after saving them but in sitesearch i cannot got those uploaded images from database dont know how to get them?

Comment: hmm so they are visible in backend but in search they are not coming, so seems its problem for search plugin .. i will test it and try to find bug there and post solution, thanks for information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this problem

```
$matching = Posting::join('fsz_posting_tblbrands') // ... do your join

// Now refetch the needed models with all needed relations
$items = Posting::with('postingimage')->whereIn('id', $matching->pluck('id'))->get();
```

Also make sure that your $item is actually an instance of your model and not only a Collection. If it is a simple Collection we won't be able to load the relations